# Cannot add packages using ArcGIS Pro Python Package Manager

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install a Python package in ArcGIS Pro but cannot get it to work. Somehow this worked for me with an earlier version of Pro. I am now using 2.6.3

The things that I have tried so far:

1. Cloning within Pro with the Python Package Manager (PPM) didn't work. So I followed the instructions [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/can-t-clone-python-environment-with-arcgis-pro-2-4-2/m-p/513201#M40309).
2. I can see the clone environment, but I cannot add packages. PPM spins for a while but nothing happens. The part of issue is that PPM doesn't echo any errors so cannot tell what the issue is.
3. Also tried the Python Command Prompt in the Arcgis Pro folder. Only then I saw that the problem was with the HTTP errors.
   `HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/esri/win-64/arcgispro-2.6-0.tar.bz2>`
   I was suspicious that it had something to do with the secure connection. So checked it with the `curl -Iv https://conda.anaconda.org` but the connection was successful.
4. Tried it as a an offline user too but still had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using the flag `-k` following @type's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/345581/16181) to [ArcGIS Pro 2.0 and Anaconda environments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289019) worked for me.

```
conda create -k --clone arcgispro-py3 --name arcgispro-py3-clone
```

I used it both for cloning and for installing a package.